# Override inclusive_categories="yes" with search string?

Tags: supersearch

Is it possible to override the inclusive_categories parameter with a search string? I want to use inclusive_categories for every case except for when a search string is passed to the results template. For example, this is my template:

```
{exp:super_search:results inclusive_categories="yes"}
    Results
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

And I want to pass a search string to the results template and set inclusive_categories="no". So I tried this string which does not work:

```
/search/locations/search?&amp;channel=locations&amp;XID={XID_HASH}&amp;category=category1+category2&amp;inclusive_categories=no
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse my ignorence if I've got you wrong, but are you simply asking how to get a value from the URL and put it into the *results* tag parameters?

I'm not 100% familiar with super search however I assume it allows the rest of the URL to be processed as a search request? channel, category, XID (ect)?

Also, in your code example you are seperating parameters with `&amp;`, is this in fact `&`?

Back to the question and assuming the above, you could use PHP to query the GET values, set your template to PHP on Input :

```
<?php
    $incCat = strtolower( ee()->input->get('inclusive_categories', true) );
    $incCat = !in_array($incCat, array( 'no', 'false', '0', 'off' ) );
?>

{exp:super_search:results inclusive_categories="<?php echo ( $incCat ? 'yes' : 'no' ); ?>"}
    {!-- Results --}
{/exp:super_search:results}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an if statement to override the inclusive_categories parameter.

If your search string is in the url and assuming inclusive_categories has "no"  as a default value, you could do something like this:

```
   {exp:super_search:results {if segment_x}inclusive_categories="yes"{/if}}
    Results
   {/exp:super_search:results}
```